# 4 wires from from power brick to 2 wire fixture

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, switching

I am attempting to hook up a 12-volt water pump to an 110 outlet.

I bought an AC/DC switching adapter to make the conversion. Intended on wiring a black and red wire to a black and red wire. But my power brick also has a blue and white wire. I'm assuming these are some sort of feedback wires for the protection of PSU's but I don't know what to do with them.

When I ignore them and just hook up the red and black wires the power supply decides to stop sending power through, it shoots small test bursts of electricity through and never powers the pump. is there an easy way to override the protection mechanism if that is what is happening? If that is not the issue what are the white and blue wires?

Power brick specs:

brand: MeanWell

model#: GS220A12

Input: 100-240VAC, 50/60Hz, 4.0A

Output:  12v 15A, 180w MAX

Comment: I'm going to guess you cut the 4-pin plug off the end of the cable and that's where you're getting those red/black/blue/white wires?

Comment: What is the max current draw of the pump?

Comment: I would be concerned about that as a supply.  DIN-4 pin plugs don't generally have a high current rating.  Even DIN-4 power plugs only go up to 10A maximum usually.

Comment: Measure them with a multimeter.

Comment: @brhans yes I cut off the 4 pin plug

Comment: @laptop2d pump draw is 11 amps

Comment: @R Drast it took me a week of searching to find one with enough amps. What other device options do I have? I'm not an electrician or electrical engineer. I know very little about this stuff

Comment: @RileyHughes That 11 amps you mentioned for the pump - is that the maximum current when the motor is first starting, or continuous operation? The pump may require much more current to get started.

Comment: For a motor, a simple transformer and rectifier would be good enough.  You do not need a regulated supply.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [datasheet](http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=GS220) (that you didn't link to) shows that there is a 4-pin connector.

[image]

- Measure each pin relative to the black wire.
- Assuming that two of them give you a +12 V reading twist those two together. They're your positive.
- Twist the other two together. They're your negative.

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get back and let you know what happens

Comment: @Riley. It's 2020 and you never got back to us as you promised. What happened?